# Kirby Diagram for the Trefoil

Tags: knot-theory, manifolds-with-boundary, 4-manifolds

I'm studying R.E. Gompf and A.I. Stipsticz, 4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus and I got stuck with a question. Let $K$ be the right-handed trefoil embedded in $\partial \mathbb{D}^4$, we know that, because of the positiveness of $K$, $g_4(K)=1$ i.e. there exists a genus 1 compact surface $\Sigma$ properly embedded in $\mathbb{D}^4$ whose boundary is $K$.

I'm looking for a Kirby diagram for $\mathbb{D}^4$ that shows the properly embedded tubular neighborhood of $\nu\Sigma = \mathbb{D}^2 \times \Sigma$.

Comment: $g_3(K)=1$ as well (and $g_4(K) \leq g_3(K)$ in general), so to get the properly embedded surface in $\mathbb{D}^4$ you can take a genus-1 Seifert surface in $S^3$ and push it off a bit into the 4-ball to make it be properly embedded. I'm not familiar enough with Kirby diagrams to know what you're looking for, but maybe this concrete description of a $\Sigma$ might help.

Comment: I knew that concrete description, I think you need an handle decomposition of that surface in $S^3$ (than underlines the trefoil as its boundary) in order to describe its embedding.

Comment: You don't need a handle decomposition. Let $\Sigma'$ be $\Sigma$ minus a tubular neighborhood of its boundary, and let $f:\Sigma\to[0,1]$ be smooth such that $f(\partial\Sigma)=0$ and $f(\Sigma')=1$, and also such that $df$ doesn't vanish anywhere on the boundary.  Choose a collar neighborhood $S^3\times[0,1]$ of the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^4$, and then consider $F : \Sigma \to S^3\times [0,1]$ by $F(x) = (x,f(x))$. This properly re-embeds $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{D}^4$ while preserving its boundary. This "stretches" a tubular neighborhood of $\partial\Sigma$ into the interior of the 4-ball.

Comment: In any case, there is an easy handle decomposition of the surface as a plumbing (a Murasugi sum) of two Hopf bands.  [Figure 6](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5866.pdf) shows the surface, the one before the arrow.